# Problems using `u8` in Substrate and ink

Tags: blockchain, substrate, parity-io, rust-ink

I am trying to add a simple `u8` to my Substrate Runtime Module:

```rust
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
        MyByte: u8;
    }
}
```

However, I get a compiler error that it does not implement Parity Codec's `Encode` or `Decode`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: _IMPL_DECODE_FOR_Event::_parity_codec::Encode` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/shawntabrizi/Documents/GitHub/substrate-package/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/template.rs:23:1
   |
23 | / decl_storage! {
24 | |     trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
25 | |         MyByte: u8;
26 | |     }
27 | | }
   | |_^ the trait `_IMPL_DECODE_FOR_Event::_parity_codec::Encode` is not implemented for `u8`
```

A similar problem occurs when I try to store a `u8` in a Substrate Smart Contract using ink!:

```
contract! {
    struct MyContract {
        value: storage::Value<u8>,
    }
    ...
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: parity_codec::codec::Encode` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:26:1
   |
26 | / contract! {
27 | |     struct MyContract {
28 | |         value: storage::Value<u8>,
29 | |     }
...  |
49 | |     }
50 | | }
   | |_^ the trait `parity_codec::codec::Encode` is not implemented for `u8`
```

Why is that, and what can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Today, the `parity_codec` does not support Encoding of `u8` due to avoid a type collision, since `Vec<u8>` is a special case from `Vec<T>`.

See: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-codec/issues/47

> gavofyork:
>
> Because it would otherwise make the two encodings: `Vec<u8>` and `Vec<T: Codec>` clash.

It is possible this could be fixed in the future with additional Rust features, but for now, you will need to store your single bytes as `[u8; 1]` and work with that type.

---

## Substrate Runtime Module

One hacky solution for a Substrate Runtime Module looks something like this:

```rust
use support::{decl_module, decl_storage, decl_event, StorageValue, dispatch::Result};
use system::ensure_signed;

pub trait Trait: system::Trait {
    type Event: From<Event<Self>> + Into<<Self as system::Trait>::Event>;
}

type U8 = [u8; 1];

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
        MyByte get(my_byte): U8;
    }
}

decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {

        fn deposit_event<T>() = default;

        pub fn set_my_byte(origin, input: U8) -> Result {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            <MyByte<T>>::put(input);

            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::MyByteStored(input, who));
            Ok(())
        }

        pub fn add_to_byte(origin, input: U8) -> Result {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            let my_byte = Self::my_byte()[0];
            let my_new_byte = my_byte.checked_add(input[0]).ok_or("Overflow")?;

            <MyByte<T>>::put([my_new_byte]);
            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::MyByteStored([my_new_byte], who));
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

decl_event!(
    pub enum Event<T> where AccountId = <T as system::Trait>::AccountId {
        MyByteStored(U8, AccountId),
    }
);
```

Where we assign a new type `type U8 = [u8; 1];`. The choice of our new type name is important since it will trick the Polkadot UI to treat this value simply as a `u8` for any input/output fields it generates. If you try to use a custom type like `type Byte = [u8; 1]`, the UI will ask you to import the definition of that custom type. If you try to use `[u8; 1]` directly, the Polkadot UI will not know how to render the input/output of that value.

Furthermore, as of the time of writing this post, the `decl_event!` macro has an issue depositing a `[u8; 1]` directly due to pattern matching.

Note that you will need to treat this type like an array when you use it. `add_to_byte()` shows an example of that. So ultimately, you need to extract the first item of the array to extract the byte, and you need to wrap your byte in an array to set a `U8`:

```
let my_byte = Self::my_byte()[0];
...
<MyByte<T>>::put([my_new_byte]);
```

Other solutions may involve using other types which are natively supported like `Vec<u8>` or `u16`, and doing the appropriate checks on your runtime that this is treated like a single `u8`, but the UI will not know better.

---

## Substrate Smart Contracts

I have not found a great solution for `ink!` yet, but you should be able to use `[u8; 1]` directly in all of your code. Again, you will need to treat it like an array for getters and setters. But when generating the ABI you will need to manually change the instances of `[u8; 1]` to `u8` to trick the UI to do what you want.